# How to update all data in jQuery.dataTables with client-side data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've been fruitlessly been trying to get jQuery.dataTables to allow me to update the data in the table using Javascript.  I know this has been discussed on SO before, but I haven't been able to make any of the solutions I've seen work.

I have a parameter called `data` that represents the data to display in the table.  It is passed into a function.

I would have thought that the way to update the data would be like this:

```
// I checked that the new data is returned by $table.data() afterwards    
$table.data(data); 
// Now that the data is updated, redraw the table.
$table.fnDraw();
```

Nothing seems to happen when the above code runs.  What am I doing wrong?

I have no trouble using fnUpdate to update the data in individual rows, so I find this particularly perplexing.

**Update:** After giving this some more careful research, I found that I can almost achieve the desired result by doing the following:

```
$table.fnClearTable();                            
$table.fnAddData(data);                            
$table.fnDraw();
```

However, the problem with the above is that the user loses his place in the pagination and has to navigate back to the page he was on.

Comment: What version of dataTables? And could we see a little example of how `data` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Well this was the issue i faced back then `Allan` suggestion worked high time for me.

**Try this :**

Using the new API you would call  [draw()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) with the parameter false. In the old API you would use fnDraw likewise (and also in [fnAddData](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnAddData) use the parameters to not redraw).

Let me know just in case .

Comment: I've tried using the `draw` function, and it doesn't seem to do redraw anything.  Only when I use fnAddData or fnClearTable or fnUpdateRow does it seem to do anything.

Comment: I presume when you use draw() you are using the access constructor for the new API - i.e. $().DataTable() (capital D). still if are unable to crack it can you try to link me to a page so i can debug it `datatables.net`